# Semantic difference between two different kinds of usage of the participle as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, participles

I am wondering what is the difference between using particles as in (1) and (2) in terms of meaning.

> (1) We need to revise the plans **devised**.

> (2) We need to revise the **devised** plans.

There are some other examples same above, I don't know what we call them grammatically; for examples *available* in:

> there are some planes **available**.

which is equivalent to (if so):

> there are some **available** plans.

What I have made out is sometimes the adjective is a phrase which would not be able to precede the noun it modifies. for example in:

> We need to revise the plans **devised for this kind of
> problems**.

But is there really any subtle semantic difference between this kind of expressions?

Comment: Of your five sample sentences, the only one that a native English speaker would be at all likely to say is ”There are some plans available.” It’s hard to discuss subtle semantic differences between constructions that aren’t actually used in practice.

Comment: @MikeScott you mean there is no usage of something like We need to revise the plans devised for this kind of problems.? I've seen this kind of structure a million times.

Comment: They differ in the sense that "We need to revise the plans devised" is like "...We need to revise the plans (that is/ that has been) devised.

Comment: @AliRasaii No, it would either be “We need to revise the plans for this kind of problem” or “We need to revise the plans that have been devised for this kind of problem”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex topic which can be researched further, for example [here.](https://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=47133)

> The researchers, through the present research, have investigated the
> different uses of both attributive-only and predicative-only adjectives.
> The present research aims at finding out the problematic areas faced
> by those who have, or like, to deal with the two subclasses of
> adjectives. As a matter of fact, most adjectives can function both
> attributively and predicatively, but some have to be used either in an
> attributive position or in a predicative position.

Your examples are using predicative adjectives, and therefore the attributive applications are incorrect, including:

> We need to revise the plans devised.
> We need to revise the devised plans.
> There are some available plans.

Actually, I'm not sure if the above mentioned rule is categorical, there may very well be situations where you can use those adjectives as attributes. However not in those sentences.

The others have reduced relative clauses. "Which are" or "which have been" are implied but omitted.

> there are some planes available.
> We need to revise the plans devised for this kind of problems.

> Is there really any subtle semantic difference between these kinds of expressions?

It’s hard to discuss subtle semantic differences between constructions that aren’t actually used in practice.